# Android NotificationListenerService cancel notification

Tags: android, notifications

I have a NotificationListenerService and a:

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Log.i(TAG,"**********  onNotificationPosted");
    Log.i(TAG,"ID :" + sbn.getId() + "t" + sbn.getNotification().tickerText + "t" + sbn.getPackageName());
}
```

How can I cancel that notification from the `onNotificationPosted()`? I tried a simple `manager.cancel(sbn.getId());` but it didn't worked

Comment: Can you show how you are passing the notification to the notification manager?

Comment: Its a firebase created background notify. So no I created.. when my app is in background then the firebase just create a notification to it, after I listening on my firebase notification posted and I need to clear that notification in the notification area, after I do this: sbn.getNotification().contentIntent.send();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :
`manager.cancel(sbn.getTag(), sbn.getId());`

If this doesn't work, you can try 
`manager.cancel(sbn.getTag(), sbn.getId(), sbn.getUser());`

You can also cancel all notifications by using :
`manager.cancelAll();`

Comment: Anybody got an idea why this fails on OxygenOS 4.1.6 (7.1.1)?

Comment: If possible can you answer this question as well? I did the same as you suggested, but it is not working for me on Android 10. [Click here for the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61478154/5716010)

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution to cancel notification from `NotificationListenerService`

```
 @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
}
```